# How to check existing value in database and change it?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table named 'Codes' and 3 Columns: id(primary), codenumber(String) and activated(Boolean, default=False)

And i have a form where i want to check value and if it exists, make activated==False for it.

I'm trying to:
myform.py:

```
#all imports here
class CheckForm(Form):
    some_code = StringField('Code: ',validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Check it!')
```

my views.py:

```
#all imports here
@some.route('/sometest', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def check_function():
    form = CheckForm()
    code=form.some_code.data
    check_code = Codes.query.filter_by(code=code).first()
    if check_code.activated == False:
        check_code.activated = True
        db.session.add(check_code)
        db.session.commit()
    elif check_code.activated == True:
        print 'Code already used'
    else:
        print 'Code not found')
return render_template('test.html')
```

But i'm getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'activated'
```

I'm using flask and sqlalchemy

Comment: Your object `check_code` is empty which means there is no row in the database with your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition for **check_code** in case no results were found in the database.

Hint: it's always more readable to handle the fail conditions on top and return from the function.

```
def check_function():
    form = CheckForm()
    code=form.some_code.data
    check_code = Codes.query.filter_by(code=code).first()
    if not check_code:
        print 'Code not found'
        return   # You don't have to worry about that again

    if check_code.activated == True:
        print 'Code already used'
        return   # Second case is already covered

    # That's the only case left, no need for an `if` condition
    check_code.activated = True
    db.session.add(check_code)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Small problem here. Now if i'm checking code first time it prints 'code not found' and if i'm do it again works properly(prints 'code already used'). Why i'm getting 'code not founds' first time?

Comment: Make sure that there's no code that creates a new entry on each access.  Because it sounds like you call this function first (which prints that the code is not found) then you do a form.save() or something that creates a new entry in the database.